# How to use templated std::function as parameter?

Tags: c++, templates

I want to make `for_each` function for 2D-vector but there is an error:

```
error: no matching function for call to ‘each(std::vector<std::vector<int> >&, main()::<lambda(int&)>)’
```

How can I fix it?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <functional>
using namespace std;

template <class VarType>
void each(vector<vector<VarType>> &ve, function<void (VarType &)> action) {
    for(vector<VarType> &v : ve) {
        for(VarType &p : v) {
            action(p);
        }
    }
}

int main() {
    vector<vector<int>> map(5);
    for(vector<int> &ve : map) {
        ve.resize(4);
    }

    each(map, [](int &val) {
        val = 1;
    });
}
```

Answer (score 5):

There are a few solutions. I would recommend to just go for a separate template parameter for the function:

```
template <class VarType, class Function>
void each(vector<vector<VarType>> &ve, Function action) {
   // no more worries
}
```

The problem is that the compiler cannot figure out the `VarType` in `function<void (VarType&)>` from the passed lambda. So doing:

```
function<void(int&)> action = [](int &val) {
    val = 1;
};
each(map, action);
```

would also work, since this way the type (`int&`) is already known.

P.S. In C++17 you can do `std::function action = [](int &val) { val = 1; };`.

Answer (score 2):

While I think taking the function as another template parameter as suggested by @DeiDei is the better solution, here is an alternative:

---

If you want `VarType` to be deduced from the first function parameter, then you can make the second parameter a non-deduced context:

```
template <class VarType>
void each(vector<vector<VarType>> &ve,
  typename type_identity<function<void (VarType &)>>::type action) {
    for(vector<VarType> &v : ve) {
        for(VarType &p : v) {
            action(p);
        }
    }
}
```

This requires C++20 for `std::type_identity` and `#include<type_traits>`, but you can implement your own `type_identity` easily:

```
template<typename T>
struct type_identity {
    using type = T;
};
```

---

This works because everything left to the scope resolution operator `::` is a non-deduced context, meaning that the template parameters in it will not be deduced from this function parameter. Your original function fails template argument deduction, because `VarType` cannot be deduced from the second parameter as the second function argument given in the call does not actually have type `std::function<...>`.